# How I manage a "mode" using a class and radio buttons in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

I have the following code in my Form1 class:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButtonActor.Checked)
            {
                MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
                Actor actor = new Actor(textBox1.Text, me.X, me.Y);

                actor.DrawActor(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
            }
            else if (radioButtonUseCase.Checked)
            {
                MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
                UseCase usecase = new UseCase(textBox1.Text, me.X, me.Y);

                usecase.DrawUseCase(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
            }
        }
```

The DrawActor and DrawUseCase methods are just lines of graphics drawing in classes called Actor and UseCase. The UI features a picturebox and some radiobuttons. Depending on which radiobutton is checked a different method is run, drawing a different picture.

Instead of using this if statement inside the Form1 class, which isn't very maintainable, how would I another class to check which radio button is checked? I'd like to do something like this:

Click on paint form >
Run method from a new class called editor > 
Method checks to see which radio button is checked > If statement here decides which method to run next.

All advice is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you facing any issue while implementing what you have described ?

Comment: currently it works perfectly, however my teacher said we are going to do ASP.NET soon and I have to separate my code from the UI. So this won't work as it is.

Comment: Buddy ! we won't be doing your homework. You need to try what you want, and if you run into any issue then ask a question about that. Refer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn't trying to hide the fact that this is homework at all! I do think however that this is specific enough

Comment: You would want to read more about MVC or related patterns that one can use to separate out logic from view.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to re-use this logic somewhere else in your code.
So you can create a class like this..

---

```
static class MyDrawer
{ 
public static void ChecknDraw(RadioButton radioButtonActor,RadioButton  radioButtonUseCase, TextBox textBox1, PictureBox pictureBox1, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButtonActor.Checked)
    {
        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        Actor actor = new Actor(textBox1.Text, me.X, me.Y);

        actor.DrawActor(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
    }
    else if (radioButtonUseCase.Checked)
    {
        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        UseCase usecase = new UseCase(textBox1.Text, me.X, me.Y);

        usecase.DrawUseCase(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
    }
}

}
```

However, After seeing your comment about using it in ASP.NET, This will not serve your purpose as the controls (TextBox, PictureBox etc ) are totally different you will not have a graphics object there nor mouse pointers.
Even this can be managed by creating the class with final values rather than passing control objects. Interesting part would be your implementation of `DrawActor` Method